# Create S/MIME with teh Java Mail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

So...

I can create and send an email like this:

```
JavaMailSender mailSender = emailSender(username, password);
MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");

messageHelper.setText(message.getText());
messageHelper.setFrom(message.getFrom());
messageHelper.setTo(message.getTo());
messageHelper.setSubject(message.getSubject());
mimeMessage.saveChanges();
mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

And now I want to add a signature to the mail. I could use the bouncycastle jars, but there is an issue. The system I am using uses a third party web service that provides a digital signature service, so I have to send the content/body of the email to this service to be signed - that's not going to change.

So now I need to take this signature and add it to the email. Any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: As posted your email has _no_ content, you'll presumably need to add that too. If the service's signature is a standard, Java-supported and S/MIME-defined, scheme, you _could_ write your own JCA provider to access it and use bcmail with that provider. If it's not standard but does have an OID, you'll need to construct the structures like SignerInfo yourself, though bc can do the ASN.1 encoding, and jmail should handle the S/MIME wrapping. (Either way is dubious for security, but that's offtopic.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The content is added by  messageHelper.setText. I'm interested to know why this is'dubious for security?' I'm trying to sign the email to prove provenance and I'm not sure why you think this is dubious

Comment: Sorry I missed the setText somehow. You should probably be explicit about the encoding because that's what you (need to) sign. It's dubious for anyone else to hold your private key (assuming it is supposedly yours in the first place), and more dubious to accept requests over the web which is generally easy to use for attacks from almost anywhere or anything. But if somebody else has already made that decision, you may not be able to change it.